# will a windows free upgrade dvd made with media creation tool work after July 29

Tags: window, upgrade

I am using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to download an ISO image of Windows 10 - the download is still running (as of 1659 July 24, 2016.

I will use that ISO to create an install DVD.

My question is: If I try to use the DVD to upgrade to Windows 10 after July 29, 2016, will it do a free upgrade?

Or does the installation itself have to occur before July 29th?

Comment: The licence is checked upon the first start of Windows. At this time Windows can connect to Microsoft Server and check if it was valid to upgrade. So I would say it is independent from the DVD. But whether Windows will close the eyes or will be strict about the date I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it isn't obvious to you what the answer is, I'd call the Microsoft Marketing Department during business hours on the West Coast.

But my *instincts* tell me that they're going to ping a server at Microsoft, and that said server is going to have a clock . . .

. . . so, if it *matters,* in some significant way, whether-or-not the process will work after this date, I reckon you've got exactly one week to find out, "straight from the horse's mouth."  **:-)**

*"Don't guess, when you can ask."*

Comment: I was thinking that using the install would be time dependent but I thought I'd ask. I think I will clone the disk, upgrade to Windows 10, and roll it back to Windows 7 and see if that successfully goes back to Windows 7 without problems. If so, I'll leave things as they are and I can re-upgrade later. I have read (several places) that you can do that.   Thank for the answer.